# How to create a dynamic generated admin fields with Image upload?

Tags: magento2, image, dynamic

> This is XML :

```
<field id="threesegmentimages" translate="label"  sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                     <field id="threesegmentimages" translate="label"  sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">   <label>Add Segment Detail</label>
                         <frontend_model>Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\ThreeSegmentImage</frontend_model>
                        <backend_model>Namespace\Module\Config\Backend\SegmentImage</backend_model>
                        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">namespage/module</base_url>
                        <comment>Maximum 12 Segment Allowed</comment>
                   </field>
```

> this is Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/ThreeSegmentImage.php

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

class ThreeSegmentImage extends AbstractFieldArray
{
protected $renderer = [];
 private $_imageRenderer;
protected function _geImageColumnRenderer() { 
if( !$this->_imageRenderer ) {
  $this->_imageRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\SegmentImageField','',['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true,]]);
    }
    return $this->_imageRenderer;
}
protected function _prepareToRender()
{
    $this->addColumn('three_segmentimage',['label' => __('Segment Image'),'size' => '50px', 'class' => 'required-entry', 'renderer' => $this->_geImageColumnRenderer()]);
    $this->_addAfter = false;;
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Segment');
}
}
```

> This is BackendModel :

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Config\Backend\;

class SegmentImage extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     */

    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'namespage/module';

    /**
     * Upload max file size in kilobytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxFileSize = 2048;

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Save uploaded file before saving config value
     *
     * Save changes and delete file if "delete" option passed
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $deleteFlag = is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete']);
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'][$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];

        if ($this->getOldValue() && ($fileTmpName || $deleteFlag)) {
            $this->_mediaDirectory->delete(self::UPLOAD_DIR . '/' . $this->getOldValue());
        }
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

I want result like this :
[image]
but not working can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: have you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Magento native approach of catalog image placeholders via **clone model**. See Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders.

1. Add text field `number_of_segments` (use any name). You will have to enter number here and save configuration for segments to pick up new number.
2. Use this field in your clone model to generate as many segments are requested.